# EL access a map value by Integer key

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have a Map keyed by Integer. Using EL, how can I access a value by its key?

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(1, "One");
map.put(2, "Two");
map.put(3, "Three");
```

I thought this would work but it doesn't (where map is already in the request's attributes):

```
<c:out value="${map[1]}"/>
```

**Follow up:** I tracked down the problem. Apparently `${name[1]}` does a map lookup with the number as a `Long`. I figured this out when I changed `HashMap` to `TreeMap` and received the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

If I change my map to be:

```
Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<Long, String>();
map.put(1L, "One");
```

then `${name[1]}` returns "One". What's with that? Why does `<c:out>` treat a number as a long. Seems counterintuitive to me (as int is more commonly used than long).

So my new question is, is there a EL notation to access a map by an `Integer` value?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Initial answer (EL 2.1, May 2009)

As mentioned in [this java forum thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9702932#9702932):

> Basically autoboxing puts an Integer object into the Map.
>   ie:

```
map.put(new Integer(0), "myValue")
```

EL (Expressions Languages) evaluates 0 as a Long and thus goes looking for a Long as the key in the map.
ie it evaluates:

```
map.get(new Long(0))
```

As a `Long` is never equal to an `Integer` object, it does not find the entry in the map.
That's it in a nutshell.

---

### Update since May 2009 (EL 2.2)

[Dec 2009 saw the introduction of EL 2.2 with JSP 2.2 / Java EE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812883/6309), with a [few differences compared to EL 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7209200/6309).
It seems ("[EL Expression parsing integer as long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269163/6309)") that:

> **you can call the method `intValue` on the `Long` object self inside EL 2.2**:

```
<c:out value="${map[(1).intValue()]}"/>
```

That could be a good workaround here (also mentioned below in [Tobias Liefke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4371659/tobias-liefke)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27533414/6309))

---

Original answer:

EL uses the following wrappers:

```
Terms                  Description               Type
null                   null value.               -
123                    int value.                java.lang.Long
123.00                 real value.               java.lang.Double
"string" ou 'string'   string.                   java.lang.String
true or false          boolean.                  java.lang.Boolean
```

JSP page demonstrating this:

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

 <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

 <h2> Server Info</h2>
Server info = <%= application.getServerInfo() %> <br>
Servlet engine version = <%=  application.getMajorVersion() %>.<%= application.getMinorVersion() %><br>
Java version = <%= System.getProperty("java.vm.version") %><br>
<%
  Map map = new LinkedHashMap();
  map.put("2", "String(2)");
  map.put(new Integer(2), "Integer(2)");
  map.put(new Long(2), "Long(2)");
  map.put(42, "AutoBoxedNumber");

  pageContext.setAttribute("myMap", map);  
  Integer lifeInteger = new Integer(42);
  Long lifeLong = new Long(42);  
%>
  <h3>Looking up map in JSTL - integer vs long </h3>

  This page demonstrates how JSTL maps interact with different types used for keys in a map.
  Specifically the issue relates to autoboxing by java using map.put(1, "MyValue") and attempting to display it as ${myMap[1]}
  The map "myMap" consists of four entries with different keys: A String, an Integer, a Long and an entry put there by AutoBoxing Java 5 feature.       

  <table border="1">
    <tr><th>Key</th><th>value</th><th>Key Class</th></tr>
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${myMap}" varStatus="status">
    <tr>      
      <td>${entry.key}</td>
      <td>${entry.value}</td>
      <td>${entry.key.class}</td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

    <h4> Accessing the map</h4>    
    Evaluating: ${"${myMap['2']}"} = <c:out value="${myMap['2']}"/><br>
    Evaluating: ${"${myMap[2]}"}   = <c:out value="${myMap[2]}"/><br>    
    Evaluating: ${"${myMap[42]}"}   = <c:out value="${myMap[42]}"/><br>    

    <p>
    As you can see, the EL Expression for the literal number retrieves the value against the java.lang.Long entry in the map.
    Attempting to access the entry created by autoboxing fails because a Long is never equal to an Integer
    <p>

    lifeInteger = <%= lifeInteger %><br/>
    lifeLong = <%= lifeLong %><br/>
    lifeInteger.equals(lifeLong) : <%= lifeInteger.equals(lifeLong) %> <br>
```

Comment: So there's no way to get EL to expand a number as an Integer?

Comment: @Steve: indeed, EL does not seem to support that.

Comment: I found this question and answer from a Google search. Sure enough, as soon as I switched from Map<Integer, String> to Map<Long, String> I was able to pull from it using the EL I had in my JSP page. Thanks!!

Comment: @Steve: It is possible - see my answer

Comment: @SteveKuo It should be indeed possible. I now realize that this 6 years old answer was written when EL 2.2 was not yet release. I have edited and updated said answer.

Answer (score 11):

Just another helpful hint in addition to the above comment would be when you have a string value contained in some variable such as a request parameter.
In this case, passing this in will also result in JSTL keying the value of say "1" as a sting and as such no match being found in a Map hashmap.

One way to get around this is to do something like this.

```
<c:set var="longKey" value="${param.selectedIndex + 0}"/>
```

This will now be treated as a Long object and then has a chance to match an object when it is contained withing the map Map or whatever.

Then, continue as usual with something like

```
${map[longKey]}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use all functions from Long, if you put the number into "(" ")". That way you can cast the long to an int:

```
<c:out value="${map[(1).intValue()]}"/>
```

Comment: I didn't saw your answer immediately. +1. I have included and documented that possibility in my answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the above post i tried this and this worked fine
I wanted to use the value of Map B as keys for Map A:

```
<c:if test="${not empty activityCodeMap and not empty activityDescMap}">
<c:forEach var="valueMap" items="${auditMap}">
<tr>
<td class="activity_white"><c:out value="${activityCodeMap[valueMap.value.activityCode]}"/></td>
<td class="activity_white"><c:out value="${activityDescMap[valueMap.value.activityDescCode]}"/></td>
<td class="activity_white">${valueMap.value.dateTime}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just happen to have a `Map` with `Integer` keys you cannot change, you could write a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function) to convert a `Long` to `Integer`. This would allow you to do something like:

```
<c:out value="${map[myLib:longToInteger(1)]}"/>
```