# Is there anyway I can convert a Map to a POJO that I can then use in JSP EL?

Tags: java, jsp, reflection

Is there anyway I can convert a Map to a POJO that I can then use in JSP EL? Maybe with reflection or something? I don't want to have to manually create a new class for every new collection of properties.

Comment: Are you trying to access a map in JSTL? Because you can do that instead of turning it into a POJO - see some examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/jstl-access-a-map-value-by-key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to do so. EL can perfectly access maps.

```
${map.key}
```

Or if the key contains dots:

```
${map['key.with.dots']}
```

You can even access it using dynamic keys:

```
${map[key]}
```