# Hashmap Error: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, hashmap, propertynotfoundexception

I created a hashmap in my SERVLET as follows:

```
 int productId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("productId"));

 HashMap cartList = new HashMap();
 Cart item = new Cart(productId, productName, price, quantity);
 cartList.put(productId, item);
```

But I have get the following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.util.HashMap$Entry' does not have the property 'productId'.

What does it mean? How can i resolve my error?

EDIT: HERE is my JSP

```
<c:forEach var="cart" items="${cartList}">
         ${cart.productId}
         ${cart.productName}
    <form method="POST" action="ShoppingCartUpdate">
        <input type="submit" value ="Update" class="loginButton" name="Update">
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action=""ShoppingCartRemove">
        <input type="submit" value ="Remove" class="loginButton" name="Delete">
    </form>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: can you please show us jsp code

Comment: What JSP code threw that error?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/jstl-access-a-map-value-by-key

Comment: @Jigar Joshi - org.life.java Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When iterating the `Map` in JSTL you are iterating its `Entry`s, so that you need to use `value` property to access their values:

```
<c:forEach var = "e" items = "${cartList}">
    ${e.value.productId}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your HashMap as such so that it knows what the type of the key/value pair are. You should always instantiate Hashmaps in this way, and I'm not sure if it will let you even without doing so. I know that in things like Actionscript you can get away with defining a Dictionary and not what types need to be in it, but in Java you must define the types that are being used and you can't use primitive types (I believe) such as int, double etc

```
HashMap<Integer, Cart> cartList = new HashMap<Integer, Cart>();
```

and the productId must be Integer and not just int

Comment: Why do I need to declare it like that? How do I know if i need to declare it? Thank you.

Comment: I agree about the declaration part but not about the `int` vs `Integer` part. Java autoboxes int to Integer in this case.

Comment: Okay I was pretty sure that I have had Java complain in the past about not declaring it as an Integer because it didn't allow primitive types as the key

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the way you're trying to read it using a JSP or something.

`$cartList[productId]` should be done. Note that `productId` is an integer variable here.