# How to use jstl foreach directly over the values of a map?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I tried the following which surprisingly does not work, looks like .values does not work at all in jstl:

```
<c:forEach var="r" items="${applicationScope['theMap'].values}">
```

The map is defined like this (and later saved to the ServletContext):

```
Map<Integer, CustomObject> theMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, CustomObject>();
```

How to get this working? I actually really would like to avoid modifying what's inside of the foreach-loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSTL access a map value by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/jstl-access-a-map-value-by-key)

Comment: @duffy: I understand that the OP wants to iterate over all values without knowing the keys.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes I do :-) But anyway I get the keys. It might sound strange, but in this case, the key is also included in the value. The key as in <key, value> is the primary key of the value object.

Comment: I am totally lost now. So my answer didn't help you? What's the functional requirement then?

Comment: The answer was absolutely ok. There is no getValues(), and this is the issue I have. Will have to work around it :)

Answer (score 37):

So you want to iterate over map values? `Map` doesn't have a `getValues()` method, so your attempt doesn't work. The `<c:forEach>` gives a [`Map.Entry`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) back on every iteration which in turn has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods. So the following should do:

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${theMap}">
    Map value: ${entry.value}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Since EL 2.2, with the new support for invoking non-getter methods, you could just invoke `Map#values()` directly:

```
<c:forEach var="value" items="${theMap.values()}">
    Map value: ${value}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

#### See also:

- [How to loop over a `Map` using `<c:forEach>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/loop-through-hashmap-java-jsp)

Answer (score 9):

you can iterate a map in jstl like following

```
<c:forEach items="${numMap}" var="entry">
  ${entry.key},${entry.value}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use this type if necessary

```
<c:forEach var="key" items="${theMap.keySet()}" varStatus="keyStatus">
    <c:set var="value" value="${theMap[key]}" />
</c:forEach>
```