# Print the value for key in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am new to jsp and using `jstl` library. I have a `HashMap` and a `List` of `Keys` to print corresponding in an ordered fashion.

I am doing:

```
<%
    request.setAttribute("obj", javaObject);  //javaObject contains a map and list
%>

<c:forEach var="x" items="${obj.listElem}">
   ${obj.map[$x]}     //does not print map content for a Key
</c:forEach>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Just get rid of the `$` in `$x`. By the way, this is not specifically JSTL, but more EL. It seems that you're new to EL as well. It's time to read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info (and also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info in order to learn what "JSTL" really is)

Comment: but I am using only jstl/core taglib. Will EL work in that case or I need to include EL taglib

Comment: Huh? It look like you didn't understood me at all. Again, just remove the `$` from `$x` in your code and it'll work. This is so extremely trivial that I can't be bothered to post it as an answer. Maybe someone else in short of reputation will do.

Comment: sorry dude. I am dont know anything JSP.
sorry for asking a stupid question.

Comment: If you try, you can find so many posts which can help you. As per BalusC please go and read the articles. Also, I would suggest to first search your problem. Someone might already asked the same problem. Here are the posts you can see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/el-access-a-map-value-by-integer-key, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164560/how-to-use-jstl-foreach-directly-over-the-values-of-a-map

Comment: I tried to search first. I couldn't, may be bacause the post you referred does not contain the keyword JSP.