# Iterate through multiple hashmap keys and display on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

I have stored the below values in a hashmap which is like this -

```
a1 - name
b1 - age
c1 - city
a2 - name1
b2 - age1
c2 - city1
...
```

I am fetching these values from the db. I am not able to figure out how to iterate through this key-value pair and display on a table in a jsp page in a particular order. I need to display it like this in the table

name  age  city
name1 age1 city1
name2 age2 city2
.
.
.

Please let me know how to do this.

Regards
Siddharth

Comment: hava a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap

Comment: https://jstl.java.net/.

Comment: you can use <c:forEach>, look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164560

Comment: @Benjamin Before the op can use jstl, he has to import the jstl core libraries into the jsp files.

Comment: @reporter yes, by writing something like: `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>`

Comment: Thanks for replying everyone. I am not sure if I made myself clear in the question. Iterating through the hasmap key-value set is not an issue. I need to display it in a certain order depending on the number of rows I retrieve from the db. Hashmap key-value set will contain each row of the db (a1-name, b1-age,a2-name,b2-age). Say the db contains 10 rows,I need to display all 10 rows with name,age etc. I know I can use lists to do it, but I have a constraint to only use hashmaps. Please let me know if there is a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use `<c:forEach items="${map}" var="mapEntry" varStatus="loop">`

and ${mapEntry.value} to get the map values inside the loop.

Comment: I managed to do it. This is what I did. Thanks for all your replies- int no_of_records = ((int) valueMap.get("no_of_records"));
            for (int i =1;i<no_of_records;i++)
            {
             %>
             <table align="center" border="1">
             <tr>
             <td> <%= (String) valueMap.get("a"+i) %> </td>
             <td> <%= (String) valueMap.get("b"+i) %></td>
             <td> <%= (String) valueMap.get("c"+i) %> </td></tr>
             </table>

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
    <tr>
        <td>${entry.key}</td>
        <td>${entry.value}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Don't forget to include this

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need to display it like this in a table (First row - name, age, city, Second Row - name1,age1,city1). Will this work in this case?

Comment: What tr and td means to you

Comment: Hashmap key-value set will contain each row of the db (a1-name, b1-age,a2-name,b2-age). Say the db contains 10 rows,I need to display all 10 rows with name,age etc. I know I can use lists to do it, but I have a constraint to only use hashmaps. Please let me know if there is a way to do this