# Iterate over enum values imported by <o:importConstants>

Tags: jsf, enums, omnifaces

Is it possible to iterate over ENUM in `ui:repeat` or `c:forEach` ?
I'm using `o:importConstants` of Omnifaces 2.5.

Example code:

```
<o:importConstants type="my.package.MyEnum"></o:importConstants>
<c:forEach var="icon" items="#{MyEnum}">
    #{icon.toString()}
</c:forEach>
```

but it comes:

```
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.MappedValueExpression$Entry@565a5787

com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.MappedValueExpression$Entry@6c01f0ce

com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.MappedValueExpression$Entry@2cd6ac37

com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.MappedValueExpression$Entry@7b6d8d37

com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.MappedValueExpression$Entry@7f8f1bb2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<o:importConstants>` converts the enum values to a `Map<String, E>` where the map key is the string representation of the enum name and the map value is the actual enum instance itself. What you're essentially attempting right now is printing each [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) instance as string. You should actually be using its [`getKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey--) and/or [`getValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue--) methods instead.

Iterating over a `Map` directly is as of now only supported in `<c:forEach>`. See also [How to use jstl foreach directly over the values of a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164560/how-to-use-jstl-foreach-directly-over-the-values-of-a-map)

```
<c:forEach items="#{MyEnum}" var="entry">
    Map key: #{entry.key} <br/>
    Map value: #{entry.value} <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

The `<ui:repeat>` (and `<h:dataTable>`) only supports it from JSF 2.3 on. Until then, you'd best iterate over `Map#values()` instead.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{MyEnum.values()}" var="value">
    Map value: #{value} <br/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Thank you! It explains a lot.