# how to access inner elements of a Map that contains Lists in JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a List of `MyBean1` in request scope (they have the name `tests`). `MyBean1` has a parameter of type `Map<Integer, List<MyBean2>>`, accessible via a method call `getMap()`. Keys of this map are numbers from 1 to 6. `MyBean2` has a method `getValue()` which returns a String.

I need the values of each list to be put in the same table cell.

I wrote something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="test" items="${tests}">
    // some stuff
    <td><c:forEach var="bean" items="S{test.map[1]}">${bean.value} </c:forEach></td>
    // repeat for keys to 2 to 6
</c:forEach>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I'm not getting the `value` fields of the List contained in the Map at key 1.

Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Spring MVC as MVC framework, and I'm able to get other fields from that `test` variable.

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/jstl-access-a-map-value-by-key

Comment: Note that EL is to be written in `${}` notation, not `S{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [EL access a map value by Integer key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/jstl-access-a-map-value-by-key) for an explanation of why it doesn't work.

If your map is a sorted map or a LinkedHashMap, iterating over its entries might work:

```
<td><c:forEach var="entry" items="${test.map}">
        <c:forEach var="bean" items="${entry.value}">${bean.value}</c:forEach>
    </c:forEach></td>
```

Comment: Thank you. I converted the key to Long and it's fine.