# Maven dependecy for EL 2.1

Tags: maven, tomcat6, el

i want to add the maven dependency for EL 2.1 with scope provided to be used with tomcat 6 but couldn't find it, any ideas where i can download it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a special tomcat version of el-api:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.35</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Unfornately the source isn't in central, use:

```
<repository>
    <id>intersult-repo</id>
    <name>Intersult Repository</name>
    <url>http://intersult.com/public/maven</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: It's in Maven Central now: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.tomcat%22%20AND%20a%3A%22el-api%22

Comment: @Arendv.Reinersdorff the binary-jar is in Maven Central, the source still isn't.

Answer (score 0):

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cel

Jeez.. I got a downvote for that although it is right there. In detail

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22javax.el%22%20AND%20a%3A%22el-api%22

or completely done all your work

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>\
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note that this is in central and it is 2.2. because 2.1 was released as 2.2 when it went final..

Comment: EL 2.2 (part of Java EE 6) is a different release than EL 2.1 (part of Java EE 5). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202686/differences-between-el-2-1-and-2-2