# JSF DataTable with value "Function parameter"

Tags: java, jsf, datatable

i don't know if its just possible but i want to create a DataTable with a value based on the value of another dataTable parent

Here the actual code (he don't work) :

```
<h:form id="searchTableAM">
           <x:dataTable id="lettersAM"
                         value="#{searchBO.listAM}"
                         var="letterAM">
                <x:column>
                    <x:div>
                        <x:outputText value="#{letterAM}"/>                            
                    </x:div>
                    <x:dataTable id="resAMID"
                                 value="#{search.serieByLetter(letterAM)}"
                                 var="resAM">
                            <h:column>
                                <x:outputText value="#{resAM.title}"/>     
                            </h:column>
                    </x:dataTable>
                </x:column>
            </x:dataTable>            
        </h:form>
```

The probleme is the value of the second dataTable (function with a parameter)
here the prototype :

```
public List getSerieByLetter(String letter)
```

ps : 1st dataTable alone work

here the result :

```
org.apache.commons.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 28.
```

Was expecting one of "}" ...

if anyone know how to fix it , or know a similar exemple code :) you're welcome

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a method with a parameter in JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273729/how-to-call-a-method-with-a-parameter-in-jsf)

Comment: Apart from that your EL version does not support it, you have a syntax error, it has to be `#{search.getSerieByLetter(letterAM)}`, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your EL version doesn' support method invokation. This was introduced with [Expression Language version 2.2](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7209200/620338) to a related question for more information.