# Access map with integer key from JSF EL

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

In a backing bean I have defined a `Map<Integer,String>` property. When trying to access the map from EL inside an xhtml-file, I get nothing back.

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{bean.myMap[0]}">
```

does not return the value for key 0. With a String key it works.

It works with a `List<String>`, but I want the Map to have some kind of sparse array (not all indexes have values)

Comment: You should use `omnifaces`: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/

Comment: @RongNK which component of omnifaces would be applicable here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSTL access a map value by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/jstl-access-a-map-value-by-key)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza So sorry, i have an mistake in memory :-)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ok, didn't know that EL in JSF is the same as JSTL.

Comment: @BjörnMilcke EL and JSTL are not the same.EL is declared by `${}` and `#{}` while JSTL is a tag library that helps working with EL. More info in their respective stackoverflow wiki pages: [EL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). Also, refer to [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets… makes sense?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3342984/1065197)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza So, then I assume this question is no duplicate to the JSTL question, although the answers are the same.

Comment: It's a duplicate question because they face the same problem and same answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EL interprets your literal number `0` as `long` type. Try a `Map<Long,String>` instead of `Map<Integer,String>`.

This is what you are supposedly doing :

```
myMap.put(Integer.valueOf(0), "SomeValue");
```

This is what EL does to get back the value :

```
String value = myMap.get(Long.valueOf(0));
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found this when I was googling for a solution. Changing the map wasn't really an option for me, since it was auto-generated code, so here's what I ended up doing.

I created a managed bean:

```
package my.bean.tool;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class Caster {

    public Caster() {
    }

    public int toInt(long l) {
        return (int) l;
    }
}
```

Then I simply did what in your case would have been:

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{bean.myMap.get(caster.toInt(0))}">
```