# Parsing HashMap containing JsonNode in .jsp per Spring MVC 3.x

Tags: json, jsp, spring-mvc, jackson, jsp-tags

How can I parse a hashmap containing a (String, Object) of json nodes in .jsp per spring mvc?

Controller:

```
 Map<String, Object> foo = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
 o o o
 // foo stores json node within the map 
 System.out.println( ( (JsonNode) foo.get("theKey")).toString() );  // Ouput-> "[100]"
 System.out.println( ( (JsonNode) foo.get("theKey")).path(0).getIntValue() ); //Output-> "100"      

 //add to view model tag
 model.addAttribute("foo", foo);
```

.jsp

```
<h1>${foo.get("theKey").path(0).getIntValue()}</h1>  // <- Returns 0!   Why?
```

EDIT:  These all work

```
<h1>${foo["theKey"].path(0).getIntValue()}</h1>  // OK! Returns 100.
<h1>${foo["theKey"].toString()}</h1>  // NO ERROR and returns "[100]"
<h1>${foo["theKey"].path(0).toString()}</h1> // OK! Returns 100.
```

============================

To add more context...I build the map from the  following json:

```
// rootNode contains all the json below...iterates and assigns to map.
for (JsonNode node : rootNode) {
    foo.put(node.path("key").getTextValue(), node.path("values"));
}
```

json

```
[
   {
      "key":"theKey",
      "values":[
         100 
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Did you tried foo[0] ?

Comment: Maybe this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/el-access-a-map-value-by-integer-key

Comment: @sam, yes tried the foo[0] and didn't get anything back. I know I can access a hashmap within .jsp as foo["theKey"] but after that not sure how to process the jsonobject. using path() and getIntValue()

Comment: @sam, looks like an issue getting the hash map.  this works. ${foo["theKey"].path(0).getIntValue()} thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the map correctly helps...jsonobject methods path() getIntValue() resolve fine.

```
<h1>${foo["theKey"].path(0).getIntValue()}</h1> // <- THIS WORKS..returns 100!
```