# Get value from hashmap based on key to JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap, jstl

I want to get the value of `HashMap` based on key.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map 
    = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

map.put("key", arrayList);
request.setAttribute("key", map);
```

What i did is

```
<c:forEach var="map" items="${requestScope.key}">
    <c:forEach var="hash" items="${map.value}">
        <option><c:out value="${hash}"/></option>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

But it seems it's printing everything, what i want to do is to get the value depends on key like: `hash.key` or something

**UPDATE:**
I did something like this but it still doesn't work

```
<c:forEach var="map" items="${requestScope.key}">
    <c:forEach var="hash" items="${map['key']}">
        <option><c:out value="${hash}"/></option>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

and the StackTrace: `Property 'External' not found on type java.util.HashMap$Entry` 
I'm pretty sure that there is really that kind of key.

Comment: You can use `${map["key_name"]}` where `key_name` is the string key i.e. `map.put("key_name", value)` and you can access the key simply as `${map.key}`.

Comment: i tried doing this one but i throws me an error heres the stacktrace: `Property 'bool' not found on type java.util.HashMap$Entry`

Comment: can you post the code as to what you did.

Comment: So you just want to print the value for the key - `"key"` of your map?

Comment: use only the inner foreach and remove the outer foreach loop. Use this in items `items="${key['key']}"` where `${key}` is the map set in request attribute.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

if all you're trying to do is get the value of a single entry in a map, there's no need to loop over any collection at all. simplifying gautum's response slightly, you can get the value of a named map entry as follows:

```
<c:out value="${map['key']}"/>
```

where 'map' is the collection and 'key' is the string key for which you're trying to extract the value.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, but note that quote marks for value are missing
`<c:out value="${map['key']}"/>`

Comment: This is what my map looks like {key1=23, key2=1, key3=0}. I get this error while using the code above: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'key1' not found on type java.util.HashMap$Node

Comment: If `key` is type of `Integer` then you should get the value using `<c:out value="${map[(1).intValue()]}"/>`  (Anwser from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/924556/2594961 )

Answer (score 4):

could you please try below code

```
<c:forEach var="hash" items="${map['key']}">
        <option><c:out value="${hash}"/></option>
  </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had issue with the solutions mentioned above as specifying the string key would give me javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException. The code shown below worked for me. In this I used status to count the index of for each loop and displayed the value of index I am interested on

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.key}"  var="map" varStatus="status" >
    <c:if test="${status.index eq 1}">
        <option><c:out value=${map.value}/></option>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```