# Checking if the object is new or holds value in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

Flow is forwarded from two controllers to a JSP. From one controller a new Object of Class A is being passed whereas from the second controller a persisted object of class A which is obtained from the db is being passed.

In JSP I need to check if the object has values or new & perform operations respectively. Can anyone tell me how do I check?

I tried this

```
<c:if test="${empty A}"> Print </c:if>
```

but it's not working.

Comment: [Is the same question from you?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20943797/1031945)

Comment: I guess your persistent object should have a non-null ID, whereas your new one should have a null ID. You could also pass an additional isNew flag from the controller to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass another attribute to identify an action,

for example:

in controller

```
request.setAttribute("action", "edit");
```

in jsp

```
<c:if test=${action eq 'edit'}">
</c:if>
```