# is it possible to change get variable values from an JSTL array like on Java?

Tags: javascript, java, jstl

I want to know how to pass the code below to jstl changing the name according to index.

```
List<Map> inventariozonas = new ArrayList<Map>();
for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++){
  Map r3 = new HashMap();
  r3.put("puntoventa", "puntoventa"+i);
  inventariozonas.add(r3);
}
```

I've been trying to get values in HTML by JSTL but I don't know how to get them dynamically due every variable has a different name.

With the code below just repeat the same value.

```
<c:forEach items="${inventariozonas}" var="r">
  <tr>
    <td>${r.puntoventa1}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Is there any possibility to do something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${inventariozonas}" var="r">
  <tr>
    <td>${r.puntoventa+index}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: the question here is, what is your purpose of all this? get all elements of each Map in the map or what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way :

```
<c:forEach items="${inventariozonas}" var="r" varStatus="vs">
  <tr>
    <td>${r['puntoventa' + vs.index]}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

1. First to get the index you can use varStatus, for more details read this [How to get a index value from foreach loop in jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825950/how-to-get-a-index-value-from-foreach-loop-in-jstl)
2. to get the value from a map you can use `r['key']`, for more details read this [Get value from hashmap based on key to JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756463/get-value-from-hashmap-based-on-key-to-jstl).

---

If you want to loop over the element of each map, then would suggest this way instead :

```
<c:forEach items="${inventariozonas}" var="myMap">
  <c:forEach items="${myMap}" var="entry">
     <tr>
       <td>${entry.value}</td>
     </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Here  ${vs.index}, ${} is not necessary cause vs.index is already inside a ${}.

Comment: thank you @Md.NasirUddinBhuiyan this is correct :)