# How do I access a dynamic list item in a forEach loop?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a forEach loop that looks like this:

```
<c:forEach var="getDetailsList" items="${getDetailsList}">

</c:forEach>
```

Each loop in the list looks like this:

```
id=1
desc=HELLO WORLD
203=1
211=0
```

id and desc are always the same but 203 and 211 would be dynamic numbers.

When I try to access 203 and 211 e.g.

```
<c:out value="${getDetailsList.203}"/>
```

I get a 500 error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Is what I'm trying to do simply not achievable with JSTL?

Comment: Hi, when you get a 500 error you should look up the actual exception and stack trace in the server logs. The answer is right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a key value pairs like a HashMap, you can always print them using key and values instead of accessing the variable directly.

```
<c:forEach var="getDetailsList" items="${getDetailsList}">
    Key is ${getDetailsList.key}
    Value is ${getDetailsList.value}
</c:forEach>
```

If it is not a key value pair, please post the stacktrace to suggest more options.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

is it a map ?? if its a map you can you below URL to refer. its possible to iterate list/map from JSTL .

[Get value from hashmap based on key to JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756463/get-value-from-hashmap-based-on-key-to-jstl)