# How to use core tags properly in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

So i have a session object from wich i wanna retrieve some data:

```
<%
HashMap<String, String> session = (HashMap<String, String>) session.getAttribute("ses");
%>
```

For this people recommend using JSTL as much as possible because this would be more efficient in JSP:

```
<c:if test="<%= !session.containsKey(request.getParameter('username')) %>">
<%
session.put(request.getParameter("username"), request.getParameter("password"));
%>
```

Is this the proper way of using JSTL tags? And this gives me an "Invalid character constant" error. This would probably be because of the single quotes used, but if i don't use them i get another error saying:

```
is quoted with ["] which must be escaped when used within the value
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756463/get-value-from-hashmap-based-on-key-to-jstl
I think you are using it wrong way it is very old fashioned of coding you can use EL Expression to fetch value from an hashmap above is the link where you can get some idea about it

Comment: Your question is slightly difficult to answer, because nothing of this all is the correct way to check if an user is logged-in or not. So even if you got the correct JSTL syntax, it would in the end still be the wrong solution for your ultimate goal. Put business logic in a servlet instead.

Comment: Is the following correct: <c:if test="${ !loginSession.containsKey(request.getParameter('username'))} "> or should expression language not be used for this example?