# Documentation of spring form path data binding attributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've tried any number of searches looking for an actual definition/description of just what is legal as a Spring form `path` and I cannot find anything. i.e.

`<form:select path="What can I put here?">`.

The closest I've been able to find is the table on this page:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html

Table 5.1 gives "examples", but they are only examples.

I really am looking for a definitive explanation of exactly what is legal in a Spring `path` and also whether any of those are limited to certain versions. I realize this is edging close to asking for favorite off-site resources but I'm looking for the information or links to the *official* documentation that covers this, not random tutorials, so it should be on topic. I can find plenty of tutorials online but I'm looking for complete reference not a basic introduction.

I'm working on a project using `spring-core-2.5.3.jar`, I'd really like to find out what is possible in that version although having reference material for more current Spring versions would be good too. I don't know how possible it will be to get an upgrade of Spring done on this project unfortunately.

To be clear - I'm aware that you can access the property `String getFoo()` using the path `"foo"`. That in some versions of Spring (which?) you can access the first element of `String[] getBar()` using `"bar[0]"`, etc.

But what are the limitations on this, are there any other things you can do?

Does it support maps and sets?

If it's a complex thing like `Map<String,List[Integer]> oof` can you do `oof["test"][3]` as the path?.

Basically the path supports a lot more than just the simple property reading but I can't find anything telling me just what the options and limitations are. Rather than just trying things and seeing what works and hoping I think of everything I'd really like to have a comprehensive list of some kind showing me just what my options are.

Answer (score 2):

Its the reference to the comand object property you want to reference by that field

so if its `MyCommand.getCheddar()`

you write "cheddar" in path.  This is part of spring-mvc, not core spring. It uses the [standard convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/924556/106261)

Comment: Yes. But if it's String[] cheddars you can also do chedder[0] - if it's some collections (which?) you can maybe do the same. If it's a complex thing like Map<String,List[Integer]> can you do chedder["cheese"][3]. Basically the path supports a lot more than just the simple property reading but I can't find anything telling me just what the options and limitations are.