# get elements stored in LinkedHashMap in jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

How to get LinkedHashMap in the jsp page which is added in ModelAndView object in the spring controller.Please see the below code:

UserDTO:

```
public class UserDTO{

    public byte[] data;
    public String user;
    public Long id;

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRequest(final HttpServletRequest request,
             HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model,
             @RequestParam("ID") String Id) {
         MyDTO myRequestDTO = new MyDTO();
        String viewName = "myData";
        final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    LinkedHashMap<Long,UserDTO> myList = myRequestsDTO.getAllRecords();
        /*  UserDTO userDoc = null;
            Long userDocKey;
            if(!myList.isEmpty()){
            for (Map.Entry<Long,UserDTO> doc : myList.entrySet()) {     
                  userDoc = doc.getValue();
                  userDocKey = doc.getKey();
                System.out.println("User  = " + userDoc.getUser() + " User Name = " + userDoc.getData());

            } } */
mav.addObject("myList", myList);//want to get this myList in jsp page and get the details from that.
return viewName;
}
```

Please suggest how to get the LinkedHashMap stored in ModelAndView object and get "userDoc.getUser() ", "userDoc.getId()" and "userDoc.getData()" from that map as i have shown in above controller code. I know that this can be achieved using JSTL but as i'm new to it please let me know the solution which is much helpful to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/el-access-a-map-value-by-integer-key

Comment: Add list into [ModelMap`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html) that is passed in arguments. `model.addObject("myList", myList);` or add it into [Model](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html) that is also passed as method arguments. `model.addAttribute("myList", myList);`

Comment: model.addAttribute("myList", myList); worked whereas model.addObject("myList", myList);  also worked but its an deprecated method. Thanks @Braj . But just curious why not it worked with mav.addObject("myList", myList); .

Comment: because `mav` is a local variable that is never controlled by spring. Only Model and ModelMap that is passed as method arguments are inspected by spring. Or you can return `ModelAndView`  object as method return type in that case it will work. Just set the view name in `ModelAndView` along with list.

Comment: You're welcome. Try last option as well with ModelAndView. Just call [ModelAndView#setViewName()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#setViewName%28java.lang.String%29) and add the object and return it.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over your map with JSTL using `foreach`.

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${myList}">
  Key  : <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>

  User : <c:out value="${entry.value.user}"/>
  Id   : <c:out value="${entry.value.id}"/>
  Data : <c:out value="${entry.value.data}"/>

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: no, i tried this now and it is not entering the <c:forEach> even if the list contains the values @obourgain .

Comment: @user3684675 Do a litmus test for the list size being returned in jsp: <c:out value="${fn:length(myList)}"/>. Let us know what you get.

Comment: Its showing me the error on the jsp page, fn:length is undefined @Prasad.

Comment: Include this in your jsp: <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

Comment: It's printing 0 in the jsp, whereas in controller when i printed size is 1.  System.out.println("---MyList ---" + myList.size()); //1 is the output @Prasad.

Comment: how can i check if list>0 in jsp: <c:if test="${fn:length(myList)}>0"> Some elements... </c:if>. This code is not working. Please suggest @Prasad

Comment: @user3684675 You need to try as: <c:if test="${fn:length(myList) gt 0}">...</c:if>