# Can the value property be used to reference a particular value of a map?

Tags: jsf

My bean has a map of Integers to Strings, I am trying to have a menu to select a value to be referred to by a certain key in the map.

My bean looks something like this:

```
public class Bean {
    Map<Integer, String> map;
    //...
}
```

and the relevant portion of my xhtml file looks something like this:

```html
<h:outputLabel value="Selection for code 5" for="code5menu" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="code5menu" value="#{bean.map.get(5)}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="good" itemLabel="good" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="bad" itemLabel="bad" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**Is there a way to do this or something similar?**

I can change the bean around some if need be. One thing to note is that the Integers aren't sequential so making a List would have lots of empty space, but if that is the only way I could still try to use a List (the Integer Key wouldn't be the index though). Maybe there's a way to do this with ajax? I looked into EL Functions but that didn't seem like what I needed.

Comment: What is your intended output??

Comment: @VighaneshGursale, I made the example a little bit more clear hopefully. Does that clear things up? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Map<Long, String>` instead of `Map<Integer, String>` as EL interprets literal number 0 as long type and it cannot be accessible. All extra details you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/el-access-a-map-value-by-integer-key)

To access Map element by key you using EL use:

```
#{bean.map[your-key]}
```

Comment: Thanks! There will be no 0 in my particular case, is it okay to use Integer instead of Long then?

Comment: @CaptainMan any *integer* you write in Facelets will be considered as `Long`, so redeclare your map as `Map<Long, String>`. That's what this answer basically tells you.

Comment: @CaptainMan If it's no way to change your Map you can use 'longToInteger()' inside your EL