# Unable to find unambiguous method: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode.get(java.lang.Long)

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a `Spring MVC` project with `Maven` managing dependencies. I need to read the JSON and display its content to the view.

Given a simple JSON object

```
{
    "items" : [{"model" : "m1"}, {"model" : "m2"}, {"model" : "m3"}]
}
```

I leverage packages from [Jackson Project](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to read and parse the file, and then set the value in `@Controller`

```
JsonNode itemsNode = Node.path("items");
model.addAttribute("items", itemsNode);
```

On the JSP, I retrieve the values

```
Item 0: ${items.get(0)}, Item 1: ${items.get(1)}, Item 2: ${items.get(2)}
```

The problem I encountered is,

everything works as expected when I use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

but I got error,

HTTP Status 500 - javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Unable to find unambiguous method: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode.get(java.lang.Long)

when I replaced both `<dependency>` to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

with no source code changes(except `import` statements). Spring is 4.1.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
${items.get(0)}
```

The JSP is treating the 0 as a Long, but `ArrayNode.get()` [takes an int](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html#get%28int%29).  Check out [the answer to this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/el-access-a-map-value-by-integer-key).  In short, you could try this:

```
${items.get( (0).intValue() )}
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. So tried `Integer.parseInt("0")` and `new Integer(0)` with no luck. And your approach works, thank you very much. But I also wonder why 0 is treated differently on different version of Jackson.

Comment: Yea I was wondering that myself.  I took a look at the Javadocs and both versions had get(int).

Comment: I was assuming it should be JEE implementation's job to interpret JSP, and found that Tomcat 8.0.9 gave me another error `Unable to find unambiguous method: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode.get(java.lang.Integer)`. But the later version of Tomcat works fine with your approach(verified on 8.0.12 and 8.0.20).

Comment: Make sure to use a recent version of Jackson: some problems with `int` vs `Integer` overloading were resolved in 2.2 or such; so version like 2.5.1 should work better.