# How to get value from map without iterator using jstl?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a string with **`,`** comma separated and a **Map**. Here is what i'm trying to get in below code.
    `<c:out value="${myUserMap}"/>`
**o/p**

```
 {1=All, 2=Admin, 3=Manager, 4=Guest}

<c:forTokens items="1,2,3,4" delims="," var="mySplit">
            <c:out value="${mySplit}"/>
           <c:out value=" ${myUserMap[mySplit]}"/>
</c:forTokens>
```

By using the above code i'm able to get all comma separated values.
If im trying to use `${myUserMap[2]}` to get the corresponding values of a map from the splitted string. I'm not getting the value.if i use two level iterator im able to get values. but i need to get values within a single iteration

Cheers.

Comment: Now im able to understand wr i missed...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/el-access-a-map-value-by-integer-key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EL access a map value by Integer key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/el-access-a-map-value-by-integer-key)