# Access hash element by variable index

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I'm refactoring 12 identical HTML form controls into a single piece of code inside a loop. I can't just loop the form because monthly values may or may not be present yet so I've built a `month` variable in the 1-12 range (so far so good):

```
<c:forEach var="month" begin="1" end="12">
    Month #<c:out value="${month}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Now I need to access items from two hashmaps:

```
HashMap<Long, String> amounts
HashMap<String, String> invalidFields
```

The old "static" syntax was:

```
<c:out value="${it.amounts[1]}"/>
<c:out value="${it.invalidFields.amount_1}"/>
```

What's the syntax to inject `month` into the mix?

Comment: Did you tried like this `${it.amounts[month]}` ?

Comment: @Swati Yes, I did. I didn't get syntax errors but the output remained empty.

Comment: You are accesing this inside loop or outside?

Comment: Inside. Right beside `<c:out value="${month}"/>`.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/el-access-a-map-value-by-integer-key) post might help you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `begin` and `end` of `<c:forEach>` are interpreted as `java.lang.Integer`, but your map keys are created as `java.lang.Long`.

```
Integer int1 = new Integer(1);
Long long1 = new Long(1L);
System.out.println(int1.equals(long1)); // false
```

So the `Map#get()` will never work for these keys.

Fix your `amounts` to be `Map<Integer, String>` instead, or use a `List<String>` instead.

Either way, then you can use:

```
${it.amounts[month]}
```

Comment: Totally right, I was in fact using the correct syntax but types didn't match. And as for the other hash map, I can also use square brackets so it's a matter of concatenating with `${'amount_'}${month}` into in a new variable and using that variable inside the brackets.